# Exporting an Excel file in Angular6 : DateTime format field is empty

Tags: angular

I implemented export to Excel as same as explained here https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular-927756ac9857.
I get xls file but only datetime fields are empty.

***visit-view.component.ts***

```
import {ExcelService} from "app/shared/excel.service";

export class VisitViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
visitViews: IVisitView[];

constructor(
    private excelService: ExcelService
){}

private excelService: ExcelService

exportAsXLSX(data: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(data, excelFileName);
}
```

***visit-view.model.ts***

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';

export interface IVisitView {
  visitDate?: Moment;
  clientId?: number;
  clientName?: string;
```

}

```
export class VisitView implements IVisitView {
 constructor(
    public visitDate?: Moment,
    public clientId?: number,
    public clientName?: string,
   ) {}
}
```

***visit-view.component.html***

```
   <button *ngIf="visitViews" (click)="exportAsXLSX(visitViews,'visits_today')" type="submit"
            class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
        <fa-icon [icon]="'save'"></fa-icon>
        <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.saveXLS">View</span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz? where I can reproduce the issue!

Comment: you can't show object  you have to define format of date as per document use dateNF  to Use specified date format in string output.checkout this https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx