# Angular 6 : Get one array from other

Tags: angular, typescript

I have array of  IVisitView where

```
export interface IVisitView {
  visitDate?: Moment;
  clientName?: string;
}

export class VisitView implements IVisitView {
  constructor(
    public visitDate?: Moment,
    public clientName?: string,
  ) {}
}
```

How to get a new array with visitDate of String type instead of Moment?

Comment: In what format do you want the dates? Please review [Moment's extensive documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) on the subject. Regarding getting a new array, `map` is purpose-built for this action.

Comment: I want to export array of IVisitView to xls . But have problem with xlsx module as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215914/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular6-datetime-format-field-is-empty. So i decided convert Momentum to String .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .map((x: IVisitView )=> x.visitDate.(some fn to format date )

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IVisitView {
  visitDate?: Date | string;
  clientName?: string;
}

class VisitView implements IVisitView {
  constructor(
      public visitDate?: Date | string,
      public clientName?: string
  ) {}
}


const visit1 = new VisitView(new Date(), 'UserName1');
const visit2 = new VisitView(new Date(), 'UserName2');
const visit3 = new VisitView(new Date(), 'UserName3');

const arr: Array<VisitView> = [visit1, visit2, visit3]

const visits: Array<IVisitView> = arr.map((v: IVisitView) => {
    if (v.visitDate instanceof Date) {
        v.visitDate = v.visitDate.toDateString();
    }
    return v;
});

console.log(visits);
```

Comment: I can't modify IVisitView